# loadmodel dont work why?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-1.2

in the sections_controller i use loadmodel to print username in sections/index file  but i get  error  :
**Notice (8): Undefined variable: user [APP\views\sections\index.ctp, line 3]**

```
public function index ()
        {

       $this->loadModel('User');
      $user = $this->User->find('all');
       $this->Section->find('threaded', array('order' => array('Section.created ASC')));
       $this->set('data','user');
          }
```

in the sections/index

```
<div><?php echo $user['User']['username']; ?></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not assigning the variable properly, try this instead:

```
$this->set('user', $user);
```

`$user` pointing to your find result and set as `user`, since that's what you're trying to call in your view. Or alternatively use the `compact` notation to achieve the same:

```
$this->set(compact('user'));
```

What you are doing now is setting a variable called `data` with the string value `user`, so when you would do this in your view:

```
echo $data;
```

It would return `user` as a string in your view.

**EDIT**

Since a find('all') will return an array, make sure you loop over the results in your view as well, like this:

```
foreach($user as $u) {
    echo $u['User']['username'];
}
```

Or if you want a specific result, call it's array key, which for the first user would be:

```
echo $user[0]['User']['username'];
```

Comment: thanks oldskool..but somethinf wrong..i uae this code but i still see the error

Comment: function index ()
        {

       $this->loadModel('User');
       $user = $this->User->find('all');
      $this->set(compact('user'));

          }

Comment: <div><?php echo $user['User']['username']; ?></div>

Comment: Try a var_dump($user) immediately after the find, what does it return?

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["User"]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["username"]=> string(5) "sara" ["password"]=> string(32) "8b5f1a32eaa8cfcbad15d045a79a0ba5" ["last_login"]=> string(19) "2012-01-12 12:10:52" ["created"]=> string(19) "2012-01-12 06:52:58" ["modified"]=> string(19) "2012-01-12 12:10:52" } } }

Comment: Ah, yes off course, there is more then 1 user, so it will be an array. See my edit to the answer above on how to retrieve that data.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo, try :

```
$this->set('data',$user);
```

and then in your view :

```
<div><?php echo $data['User']['username']; ?></div>
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: justn..something wrong...i chanche code and it is not work too

Comment: what is the error message ? how did you change the controller/index and the view ? please try debug($user) in your view and paste the result

Comment: function index ()
        {

       $this->loadModel('User');
       $user = $this->User->find('all');
      $this->set(compact('user'));

          }

Comment: <div><?php echo $user['User']['username']; ?></div>